# Data structure to implement a map and is optimized for lookup for frequently used keys

Tags: performance, data-structures, dictionary

The data structures I know such as b-tree or rb-tree do not change when I keep looking for the same keys. I'm looking for a data structure which optimizes itself in the runtime for faster lookup for frequently used keys. Now I have a naive implementation like this:

```c
ValueType MyNaiveMap::get(KeyType key) {
  innerMap.addFreq(key);
  if (key == mostFreqUsedKey1) {
    return val1;
  } else if (key == mostFreqUsedKey2) {
    return val2;
  }
  else {
    return innerMap.get(key);
  }
}
```

The keys are always `int` in my case.

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention hash map. Because the map may grow to a very large size, I was trying to avoid resizing which is O(n) complex in the runtime.

Comment: What about a hash map? Are you aware of the concept of hash functions?

Comment: Do you know the size of your map ahead of time? If you did, you could avoid the resizing.

Comment: And do I understand you correctly that average case O(log n) with worst case O(log n) (balanced tree) is better for you than amortized average case O(1) with worst case O(n) (resizing hash map)?

Comment: It can grow up to 100G in memory. I can allocate the memory ahead to avoid resizing. Besides that, I think I should use less than 50% capacity of the hashmap to get good performance. I would waste 50G memory, correct?

Comment: @woodings Hash maps waste memory on empty space, trees waste memory on pointers, so it's not that tree will use 50 % less memory.

Comment: @svick nice! I didn't realize that!

Comment: What about a Splay Tree? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the total size ahead of time, or if O(n) insertions due to resizing (but still O(1) amortized in the average case) are okay for you, then I think hash table is the best option. The one-time hit of copying the whole table when resizing can also be distributed over several operations by using [incremental resizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Incremental_resizing).

You have to keep the hash table partially empty to avoid collisions, which may feel like wasting memory. But with tree-based maps, you usually have at least one additional pointer per item, which will also “waste” a significant amount of memory. Also, with a hash table, you can tweak how much of it to keep empty, partially trading performance for memory (or vice versa).

But there also is a tree-based data structure optimized for looking up recently accessed keys: [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). It uses rotations to keep recently used keys near the root, while still maintaining amortized worst case of O(log n) for insertion and searching. (That “amortized” bit is important, some operations can still be O(n)).

Answer (score 1):

You could internally track the most X used value/keys.  Have a quick cache for these values that you check first (before checking the larger data tree).  Track how many times an item has been accessed/viewed.  If on a view, that item was viewed more then the last item in the list, you can figure out placement in the mini list.  This way, to see if you add a new item to this quick look up you only need to check the last value in it to see if it needs to be replaced.

Periodically resort the top look up values.

Comment: How to 'internally track the most X used value/keys'? I was thinking about this. But I found out that I probably need a min/max heap to keep track of the used numbers. Then it turns out to be O(logN) for each lookup which is the same as normal maps.